# Shopify time lag CSS Application

Tags: shopify, pageload

I have a Shopify store running at https://www.2two.be/..

Especially on mobile, but also sometimes on desktop, there is a small time lag between seeing the page and my css being applied. For a split second you can see pure html.

I have on page css. Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

This is the head code from my theme.liquid file..

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">  
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow"> 
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/3064/1060/files/twologonew.jpg?v=1619600091" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.3.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Central CSS and JS Files -->
    {{ content_for_header }} 
    {{ 'website.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}  
    {{ 'application.js' | asset_url | script_tag }} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/tuc2hbj.css">   
    <script> 
      (function(d) {
        var config = {
          kitId: 'imy7djc',
          scriptTimeout: 3000,
          async: false
        },
        h=d.documentElement,t=setTimeout(function(){h.className=h.className.replace(/\bwf-loading\b/g,"")+" wf-inactive";},config.scriptTimeout),tk=d.createElement("script"),f=false,s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a;h.className+=" wf-loading";tk.src='https://use.typekit.net/'+config.kitId+'.js';tk.async=true;tk.onload=tk.onreadystatechange=function(){a=this.readyState;if(f||a&&a!="complete"&&a!="loaded")return;f=true;clearTimeout(t);try{Typekit.load(config)}catch(e){}};s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk,s)
      })(document);
    </script>   
</head>
```

**Solution**
Part of my markup (css) was inline. Particularly that of my index and blogpost articles pages. Inline css was loaded only after page html was loaded, which caused some problems. I have moved all my page-specific css to my external css file. This solved the problem..

Comment: please move website.css in the head. CSS must be load before all content

Comment: Hello Kashif, thank you for your reply! I have added my head code in question.. CSS should be loaded, no?

Comment: move {{ 'website.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}  to before <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/tuc2hbj.css">

Comment: I have moved the stylesheet link as in updated question code, but problem persists..

Comment: Also, this is a typekit link, so this is used to load the Adobe fonts used in project. Problem is linked to overall css load, not to font versus rest of css load..